# Use php to create counting upward html files?

Tags: php, html

I would like to know if I could create a new php file everytime someone clicks a button. The button looks like this:

```
<button onClick="generate.php"> Generate </button>
```

PHP:

```
What do I do here?
```

I would like the page generated to be a number that goes up for every button click. So, 50 pages have been generated, so the next click makes a file named "51.html", and so on.

I know that for the log, you have to do something like this:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('countlog.txt', 'r');
$dat = fread($fil, filesize('./class/countlog.txt')); 
$write = fwrite($file, $data+1);
echo $data;
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: you might want to store the counter value somewhere instead of relying on the existing files to retrieve the current number.

Comment: FIRST,why do you want to do that?

Comment: $write = fwrite($file, $data+1); this will proably just append a 1 as string to the data.

Comment: I don't have the best php skills yet, but I am taking a course. I tried making  another one of these under this one, but making the file name a number and at the end it writes to the number-named file + 1. Didn't work.

Comment: I want to this because my site is going to have a random class generator for a game, so I want them to be able to generate a random class for fun with friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try This

```
<?php 

define('START_FILENAME', __DIR__ . "/starting_point");

if (file_exists(START_FILENAME))
{
    # There is that File - read its content
    $start = (int) file_get_contents(START_FILENAME);
}
else
{
    # No File Found - Create new File
    $start =  0;
    @file_put_contents(START_FILENAME, "$start");
}

# When Form Submitted
if (isset($_POST) and isset($_POST['Click']) and $_POST['Click'] == "Generate")
{
    $file_name = "{$start}.html";
    @file_put_contents($file_name, "Hello World!");
    # Update Counter too
    $start = $start + 1;
    @file_put_contents(START_FILENAME, "$start", 0);
    echo "Generated Filename - $file_name";
}


?>
<form action="demo.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="submit" name="Click" value="Generate">
</form>
```